# Am i correctly setting up this static method?

Tags: java, class, methods, static-methods

Instructions: Write a static method createAdult for Person that returns a special instance of this class. The instance represents a generic adult and has the name "An adult" and the age 21.

Person is the class name
name is a String variable private
Age is an int variable private

This is what i created, Is this all it is asking for? Is it asking for more than i have provided?

```
public static void createAdult(String name, int age)
{
  name = "An Adult";
  age = 21;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I cant help you to finish your homwork, so let me try to explain.

The requirements are:-

- return a special instance of this class. 
  How is your method returning anything? If you declare void, that means your method is not returning anything.
- The instance represents a name and age, so you have to return an instance of that class in your static method. Create a new instance with those values.

Answer (score 2):

No. As the first line of your question states, you have to create an *instance* of the class (using the `new` keyword), then assign those values to it, then return it.

Most likely there will be a constructor for `Person` which will do what you want, something like:

```
Person newPerson = new Person ("paxdiablo", 46)'; // A rare admission :-)
```

A static method is not attached to an instance so you cannot set the fields of an object unless you create one.

[This page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) covers the instantiation of objects. [This page](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=21) covers factory methods (which is what you're trying to do here - the "factory" is a device capable of building objects as needed and giving them back to you, as distinct from you creating them yourself).

For example, if you look at that second link above, you'll find:

```
public static ComplexNumber valueOf (float aReal, float aImaginary) {
    return new ComplexNumber (aReal, aImaginary);
}
```

This is a classic factory method, a static function you can call with:

```
ComplexNumber c = ComplexNumber.valueOf (0, 1); // sqrt(-1)
```

and that will create an object to your specification.

Comment: okay so i cannot manually set it as i have it, instead i need to create the instance instead and have the constructor values of name/age be equal to what i am trying to establish.

Comment: Yes, @Burninfate, that's correct. Instantiate an object to spec then return it. The classic factory.

Comment: I am a bit confused, how am i supposed to call the method from my tester program to see if it works, It does not look like the usual method, or would i insert it into another method.

Comment: @Burninfate: you call it with the class qualifier rather than an instance qualifier. If your class is `Xyzzy`, a static method is called as `Xyzzy.staticMethod();`. A non-static is called as `Xyzzy plugh = new Xyzzy(); plugh.nonStaticMethod();`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only code is what you have provided us then no, it won't work.  You can't assign to name and age in your code.

Answer (score 0):

- The method createAdult should only return the instance of the Class.
- With void you will return nothing
- The name and the age should be in the class and not in the method